# Android Development: How do I integrate threads in this?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

So I'm trying to make a youtube application by retrieving the json data from a youtube channel. Problem is I'm great at writing single-threaded applications. But when it comes to multithreading I always lose my insight.

I haven't learned it in school yet and most tutorials are rubbish, or atleast I find that.

So what I want to do is introduce a thread to my "GetVideos" class so it doesn't slow down my application while retrieving the videos. I know I'll have to use a handler and thread but everytime I try to use them my application crashes. Can you guys help?

```
public class GetVideos { //class that retrieves JSON data based on youtube username

private String channelName;
private HttpClient client; //client that gets info
private VideoLibrary lib;


public GetVideos(String channelName) {
    this.channelName = channelName;
    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    lib = new VideoLibrary();
    fillData();
}

private void fillData() {
    try {
        final String URL = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/" + channelName + "/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc";
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(URL);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
        String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("items");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject items = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String title = items.getString("title");
            String thumbUrl = items.getJSONObject("thumbnail").getString("sqDefault");
            String url = items.getJSONObject("player").getString("default");
            lib.addVideo(new Video(title, url, thumbUrl));

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
       }
   }

    public VideoLibrary getLib() {
         return lib;
    } 
 }

public class SxePhil extends Activity { //class that makes up the interactive end of
//the app, here the JSON data is put in a list 
private ListView list;
private GetVideos g;
private VideoLibrary videoLibrary;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sxephil);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sxephilList);
    g = new GetVideos("sxephil");
    videoLibrary = g.getLib();

    ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        titles.add(videoLibrary.getVideos().get(i).getTitle());
    }


       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, titles);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
   }  
}
```

Basically what I tried was implementing the threading that is used here: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/show-youtube-user-videos-in-a-listview/

in my code, because this project was built on an older sdk, so I wanted to modernize it so to speak. Look at the GetYoutube*** class and MainActivity class that's where the money is

Comment: Would be better off showing us what you tried and we can point out to you why it's not working and how to fix it. Also, it would be better to use an AsyncTask than a handler imo.

Comment: +1 for 'most tutorials are rubbish' - sad, but true:(

Answer (score 0):

You should either use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or even better, a [Loader](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html), they automatically handle the treads for you

Answer (score 0):

First : basic advices (that you MUST remeber and follow)

- Never do processing in a class constructor (that's bad OO design, imho)
- Never, **ever** leave time-consuming process in Activity.onCreate method (and in general, in any method that is runned by the UI Thread, ie. onResume(), onClick(), ...)

mario and runor49 were right : you should use an AsyncTask here (and you must read and understand http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads. If you don't, read it again...)

Basically, you should do the following :

1. onCreate must launch a separate thread, which will contain the "long" processing (load the data from network)
2. When done, this thread must call the Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable), where the runnable will create the Adapter and assign it to the ListView.

Here is a code sample :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    loadDataInThread();
    }

private void loadDataInThread() {
    new Runnable() {            
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // LOAD DATA FROM NETWORK
            displayDataInUIThread(datas);
            }
        }.start();
    }       

private void displayDataInUIThread(final VideoLibrary data) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, data);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });
}
```

This is a very basic (and rude) way to do it, and the AsyncTask way () way will be far better, but it should be working and fill the contract...

Comment: You need to make displayDataInUIThread() synchronized to avoid a probable race condition.

Comment: @SkyKelsey nope, `runOnUiThread` already "synchronizes" whatever it executes because it runs on a single thread and you can't race with yourself. You only need synchronization if two+ threads can modify data at the same time - can't happen here unless you touch `datas` inside the runnable in `loadDataInThread` after it was send back to the UI thread.

Comment: You are my hero! :D I used an AsyncTask after implementing your code first to understand what I was doing. And btw I only put that task in the constructor because I wanted it to work temporarily. I knew it didn't belong there. You shouldn't run when you're born

Comment: @zapl You are right. As long as the only thing happening in displayDataInUIThread() is adding a thread to the UI message queue :)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this most easily using an AsyncTask. Check out this tutorial.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html